# Looking for an RTF editor to use in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: annotations, text-editor, eclipse-rcp, rtf

I am making an Eclipse RCP Application in which I would like to include the possibility of editing RTF files. It would be a plus to be able to easily handle annotations.

I have already looked at org.eclipse.epf.richtext and it doesn't really fit the requirements.

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas:

- The rich text viewer [link text](http://www.onpositive.com:8000/richtext/) looks nice and is eclipse open source.
- If you are using windows you can embed an ole-frame in your application. Examples at http://www.java2s.com/
- There is an article about an rtf editor in the eclipse magazine (in german) "Multimedia-Redaktionssystem auf RCP-Basis". [Article](http://www.sphinx.at/it-consulting/upload/pdf/ECM_01.20009.pdf), [source code](http://it-republik.de/zonen/magazine/ausgaben/psfile/source_file/22/weissboeck4933f30add721.zip).
- Have a look at the [open office integration editor plugin](http://ubion.ion.ag/solutions/003officeintegrationeditor)